# How to wrap Spring beans

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring framework..

Here is my question: How i can wrap beans in runtime onto another class?

I have classes as follows for every data struct && java type:

```
@Component
    public class ByteCodec extends Codec<Byte> {
    public ByteCodec() {
        super(Byte.class);
    }

    public void encode(... buffer, Byte object) {
        buffer.writeByte(object);
    }

    public Byte decode(... buffer) {
        return buffer.readByte();
    }
}
```

and this class is a managed spring singleton.
I need to wrap that codec by next class:

```
class OptionalCodec<T> extends Codec<Boolean> {
    public OptionalCodec(Codec<T> clazz) {
    }
    ... some implementation of encode && decode method's ...
}
```

How i can do this?
Hint: i want automatic wrap in RUNTIME for every Codec instance..

And how to extend Autowired annotation, like that:

```
@AutowireCodec(targetClass=Integer.class, canBeNull=false)
private Codec<Integer> codec;
```

And how to do registry of the all runtime-created codecs with map:

```
Map<*MyCodecInfoClass*, Codec>
```

??
Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring allows you to inject beans by types and generic types out of the box, so for your use case I don't think it is really necessary to create a new Autowired annotation. You can simply use the existing @Autowired like this:

```
@Autowired
private Codec<Byte> codec;
```

Just keep in mind that if you define more than one bean for the same generic type and you use the code above, you'll get an error because more than one bean exist with that definition. You could get around that injecting a collection instead of a single object, for example:

```
@Autowired
private List<Codec<Byte>> byteCodecs;
```

Or if you want all codecs, regardless its generic type you can simply do something like this:

```
@Autowired
private List<Codec<?>> allCodecs;
```

Regarding your question on instance wrapping, I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're trying to achieve but you can inject a codec into another codec like I stated above, or you can take a look to Spring AOP and use it to wrap calls to your beans: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

---

I'm still not sure what would be the purpose of of the `OptionalCodec` as it will accept booleans on the encode/decode methods. The `OptionalCodec` is a different class than the base `Codec` interface, so if you do:

```
@Autowired
private OptionalCodec<Byte> codec;
```

Will inject the optional Byte codec. If you do:

```
@Autowired
private Codec<Byte> codec;
```

Will inject the original Byte codec. But if you do:

```
@Autowired
private Codec<Boolean> codec;
```

It will match all the `OptionalCodec` beans (because the type signature for an `OptionalCodec` is `Codec<Boolean>`) and throw an error as it will not be able to pick a single one.

That said, if you really need to fine tune the autowiring of same type of beans I suggest you to check this relevant section of Spring documentation where annotations like `@Primary` and `@Qualifier` are explained, and let you do exactly that: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: Thank for answer!Sorry for my english..
I want to add some like a beanpostprocessor for handle all Codec beans, and wrap codec object instances in  OptionalCodec and register in spring container by new bean name.
.. i.e. I have byteCodec bean, when singleton created i need to handle it 
and wrap to OptionalCodec with new name : optionalByteCodec..
How to do that?
Here is my wrapper method: http://pastebin.com/CqWiujzA (codecRegistry is simple Map<*CodecInfo*, Codec instance>.. clazz - is a target class supported by codec, codec is a codec instance..
Maybe spring have managed registries?

Comment: custom autowired annotation is requied: how spring understand what codec i need to autowire? byteCodec or optionalByteCodec?

Comment: You will not be able to define new beans using a BeanPostProcessor, you can only process existing beans before and/or after their initialization with it. This means that if you implement the wrapper as a BeanPostProcessor, you will end up with the same number of beans but all wrapped inside OptionalCodecs, not the original bean and the optional as different one.

Comment: In order to modify (or add) beans definitions, you could do it with a BeanFactoryPostProcessor, but it keep in mind that this gets executed before any bean get instantiated, so you'll have to deal with the bean definitions directly and it can get pretty messy and error prone. Do you really need a handle to both wrapped and unwrapped instances? Check the additional info on the answer. Hope that clarifies a bit!

Comment: i fixed issue: remove spring container from core project and use own CodecRegistry and codecs registration service;)
now all codecs stored in xml's..